# How to create a range of numbers from 1 to 5 in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to get as a result `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` in array. What am doing wrong? Do I have to decrease `endNum`?

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (endNum - startNum >= 0){
    const array = rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum);
    array.push(startNum);
    return rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum);
  } else {
    return [];
  }
};
console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5));
```

Comment: As a comment, it's certainly not the right way to use recursion

Comment: recursion blowed my mind certainly.if i understand it clearly,i would have deep inside:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript function similar to Python range()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273047/javascript-function-similar-to-python-range)

Comment: @rickdenhaan I think that the question is why isn't this working, not how to solve the general problem

Comment: How do you expect this to ever terminate? If `endNum - startNum` is more or equal to zero then `endNum - startNum + 1` would also be.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Fair enough, I've been bashed lately for "anwering obvious dupes" so maybe I'm growing too quick to mark questions as duplicates now :-)

Comment: You get stuck in an infinite loop because the first thing your function does is to call itself with the exact same parameters

Comment: thanks i took my answer.Really it is my second question here.Very helpful and informative.I will use different version of solving method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job with for loop.

```
function rangeOfNumbers(a, b){
 let arr = [];
 for(a; a<=b; a++){
  arr.push(a)
 }
 return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log([...Array(6).keys()].slice(1))
```

OUTPUT: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

"Under the hood" an array in JavaScript is actually an object with keys that are integers. The code spreads the keys of an array of length 6 to another array.

The slice method returns the second through the last element.

If you are looking for a range function, try this:

```
var range = (start, stop, step=1) => {
    const length = Math.ceil((stop - start) / step);
    return Array.from({length}, (_, i) => (i * step) + start);
}

range(1, 6)
```

OUTPUT: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

### Short and concise:

[Read about this method in this great anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33352604/104380)

```js
const rangeOfNumbers = (a,b) => [...Array(b+1).keys()].slice(a)

console.log( rangeOfNumbers(1,5) )
console.log( rangeOfNumbers(5,10) )
```

The above isn't ideal when the parameters are quite large numbers, the code will needlessly generate a large array only for a small slice:

```
rangeOfNumbers(1000000,1000005)
```

Let's try to make a function which is more "considerate" on resources:

```js
const rangeOfNumbers = (a,b) => [...Array(b-a)].map((_,i) => i+a+1)

console.log( rangeOfNumbers(1000000, 1000005) )
```

Comment: Hi @Alex - OP did not specify he wants recursion in the title not the description of his question, therefore I am surprised you say OP wants that, and even so, if he does, then OP did not convey that in any way.

Comment: I was guessing he tried to solve it with recursion because that just happened to be what OP came up with. I try to go by the title of questions, since it should be the essence and future people will come here from Google seeking help and click **because** of the title, and they probably will gain more value from my answer than the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

[Getting range numbers using recursion in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175342/getting-range-numbers-using-recursion-in-javascript)

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
 if (startNum - endNum === 0) {
  return [startNum];
 } else {
  const numbers = rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum);    
  numbers.unshift(startNum);
  return numbers;
 }
};
```

Comment: thanks you.i have created infinite loop by endNum - startNum >= 0

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 const array=Array();
    function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
      if(endNum-startNum>=0){
        console.log(startNum)
        array.push(startNum);
       return rangeOfNumbers(startNum+1,endNum);
        
      }else{
        return array;
      }
    };
    console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1,5));
```